# Printwriter not outputing leading zeros to text file

Tags: java

So this code I'm trying to output to text file in a certain format so that when I load it it wont have any problems. I'm using `String.format("%02d", 5)` to output `05` instead of just `5`. This works in console but when outputing to text file it seems to output as 5 not 05. Why is this happening?

```
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(scheduleFile);

for (int i = 0; i < getSchedule().length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < getSchedule()[i].length; j++) {
        output.print(j + ":00-" + (j + 1) + ":00     =");
        if (getSchedule()[i][j] != null) { // if not null
            output.print(String.format("%02d", (j)) + ":00-" + String.format("%02d", (j+1)) + ":00     "); // print hours
        }
        output.println();
    }
}
```

Text file looks like this:

```
0:00-1:00     =  
1:00-2:00     =  
2:00-3:00     =  
3:00-4:00     =  
4:00-5:00     =  
5:00-6:00     =  
6:00-7:00     =  
7:00-8:00     =  
8:00-9:00     =  
9:00-10:00     =  
.  
.  
.
```

should look like this:

```
00:00-01:00     =  
01:00-02:00     =  
02:00-03:00     =  
03:00-04:00     =  
04:00-05:00     =  
05:00-06:00     =  
06:00-07:00     =  
07:00-08:00     =  
08:00-09:00     =  
09:00-10:00     =   
.  
.  
.
```

Comment: It means that this line prints to your file `output.print(j + ":00-" + (j + 1) + ":00     =");`, not this one `output.print(String.format("%02d", (j)) + ":00-" + String.format("%02d", (j+1)) + ":00     ");`. Just add `String.format` to the first `output.print` line.